# How can I create a script to map network printers with different print servers?

Tags: windows, powershell

Hello I have the following code I use to get the list of network printers from the server and install a printer based on the number selected but I am having issues with the installation part

```
$global:Server = $Null
$global:Server = Read-Host "Enter name of Server"
$global:FullServerName = "\\$global:Server"
$global:i=0
get-Printer -ComputerName $global:FullServerName|
Select @{Name="Item";Expression={$global:i++;$global:i}},
Name -OutVariable menu | format-table -AutoSize
$r = Read-Host "Select Printer to install by typing the number"
$Printer = $menu | where {$_.item -eq $r}
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $global:FullServerName\$Printer.Name
```

Everything works and I get the list of printers in the format that I want but I get an error when trying to install it saying that the server or printer name is not found.

When I do an write-host output of $global:FullServerName$Printer.Name I get an output of
\ServerName@{item=1, name=PrinterName}

When I do an output of just $Printer.Name I get just the name of the name of the printer so I'm guessing this is where the error is happening as it is not getting just the name of the printer to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $global:FullServerName\$Printer.Name
```

`$Printer.Name` is parsed as `$Printer` concatenated with ".Name", you need to tell powershell that the whole thing is a single expression, like this:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $global:FullServerName\$($Printer.Name)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, type the two different code lines in an IDE, the distinction should be clear, as in the first case, the "Name" will be highlighted as a string

Comment: Yup this is perfect exactly what I needed  thank you so much